# Difficulty with 'any' in NumPy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am using Python 3 and am trying to check if the sqrt of elements in array2 are in a. I am returning the boolean response.

I am receiving the error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

My code:

```
import numpy as np

def mems(a, b):
    a = np.array(a)
    b = np.array(b)
    return np.any(np.sqrt(b) in a)
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess, return part is wrong. Try this:

```
import numpy as np

def mems(a, b):
    a = np.array(a)
    b = np.array(b)
    b_sqrt = np.sqrt(b)
    return any(sqrt in a for sqrt in b_sqrt)

print(mems([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [20, 56]))
print(mems([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [16, 25, 17, 18]))
```

Output:

```
False
True
```

Comment: Casting the input parameters to a different type and reusing the variable is pretty common.  There is nothing wrong with doing so.

Comment: I don't think you need the list comp in `any` -- that will just consume memory needlessly.

Comment: @erip It's possible

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy function in1d for this

```
import numpy as np

def mems(a, b):
    return np.any(np.in1d(a, np.sqrt(b)))
```

But you will get wrong results if you do this with nonintegers.